# ManualResetEvent will block all my thread or only my object thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I have a `winform` application that hosts a `WCF` service.

This application supports multiple clients and each client sends a `string` to my application which represent a file name.  My application starts to process and do the job.
After the process ends (each process is opened for a limited time) my process raises an exit event.

The file that created the process to copy the file to a new location, then deletes the old file. At this point, most of cases fail because my file is still in use. So I wonder how to handle this.

This is how i am open my process:

```
        ProcessStartInfo tsharkStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        Process pros = new Process();
        tsharkStartInfo.FileName = processToInvoke;
        tsharkStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        tsharkStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        tsharkStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        tsharkStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        tsharkStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        tsharkStartInfo.Arguments = args;
        pros.StartInfo = tsharkStartInfo;
        pros.ErrorDataReceived += pros_ErrorDataReceived;
        pros.OutputDataReceived += pros_OutputDataReceived;
        pros.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        pros.Start();
        pros.BeginOutputReadLine();
        pros.BeginErrorReadLine();
        pros.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        pros.Exited += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        {
            if (ProcessExitedEvent != null)
                ProcessExitedEvent(pros.Id); // Raised this event when my process exit
        };

private void processExitEvent()
{
   // copy the file to new location
   // delete the old file
}
```

So should I do something like this:

```
ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);

private void processExitEvent()
{
   // copy the file to new location
   mre.WaitOne(2000); // wait 2 seconds to ensure my file not longer in use
   // delete the old file
}
```

So my question is, will this solution block only the current thread or all my client threads?

Comment: It will block the thread that `mre.WaitOne(2000)` was called on. If you call `mre.WaitOne(2000)` on other threads they will be blocked too.

Comment: This is a nonsensical use for WaitOne(), you might as well call Thread.Sleep().  Arbitrarily waiting 2 seconds is nonsensical as well, there's no guarantee whatsoever that it is enough.  The only thing that makes sense is you dealing with the file being locked when you try to open it again.

Comment: And really... I don't understand why the file MIGHT still be open.  Once the Exit event is fired off, the file should be closed... always.

Comment: Sounds like you aren't closing a file handle somewhere. Consider a using() block to wrap the IO operation

Answer (score 0):

It would only block the *current* thread. If it would block all threads, there would be no thread able to call `mre.Set()`!

If all you want is to wait (`mre.Set()` not called anywhere), you could use `Thread.Sleep(2000);` instead.

Comment: But Thread.Sleep will block all my UI, maybe another solution ?

Comment: In that case you could set a timer, or execute this code on a separate (not the UI-) thread.

Comment: Can i have an example ?

Comment: There are plenty of examples of how to use a timer in winforms. For example http://www.dotnetperls.com/timer.

Answer (score 0):

I feel there are a few problems with your approach...

First of all, it sounds like you're swimming with race conditions... Adding a `sleep(2000)` might fix it this time... but not everytime.  It's definately the wrong approach.  You want to make sure that the file will ABSOLUTELY be closed before you proceed.  Which means, the file should be closed before the `event` is ever raised.

Second of all, it sounds like you're trying to do things to a file that has not yet been closed...

A solid approach in C# to always avoid this, is to use a `using` block.

So lets say you have something like this:

```
using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(x))
{
  // Copy the file...

  // End of scope - This will close the file.
}

// Raise exit event.
```

The nice thing about using a `using` statement is that you know for certain, as soon as you exit this block... the file will be closed.

Ultimately... you just want to avoid having to ever rely on something like `sleep(2000)` or even `WaitOne(2000)`. These could yield unpredictable results.

Comment: See my update, added how i am open my process, where i need to add the using ?

Comment: First of all... you should register to the event BEFORE you start it.  What if the process finishes before you register? You would miss the event!  Second, does the file copying happen inside the `ProcessStartInfo`?

Comment: the file copy inside my ProcessExit event (another class)

Comment: Why is the file not closed before the exit event?  Do you own the `ProcessStartInfo` code?

Comment: the file copy after the exit because i want to delete the file after the copy and because i think that batter, can i have code example how to do it ?

Comment: I'm just asking if you can change the code of `ProcessStartInfo`?